# Drupal 8 Custom Form managed_file multiple upload field restrict limit number of upload files

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, managed-file

I have a custom form in Drupal 8. Form has managed_file field with multiple true. I am facing challenge regarding the limit of number of files upload to this field.

I have to make this managed_file field to upload only 3 images.

Can someone help me regarding this?
I have tried below code.

```
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['upload_doc'] = array(
          '#type' => 'managed_file',
          '#title' => 'File Upload',
          '#upload_location' => 'public://upload_document/',
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#multiple' => TRUE,
          '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg png'),
            'file_validate_size' => 2000,
          ),
        );

    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        ];

        return $form;
}

public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {      
      $fileObj = $form_state->getValue('upload_doc');
      if (count($fileObj) > 3) {
        drupal_set_message('File limit exceed'.count($fileObj), 'error');
        return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }
```

The problem is, i am not able to validate file upload limit. It's allow to upload more than limit. Please help me
Thank you

Comment: can you share  what you've got `$form_state->getValue('upload_doc')`, is it array? object ?

Comment: @Yusef: I am able to get file object with all file properties like size,name etc..

Comment: is it an array of  file objects or just one file?

Comment: array of file Objects. able to get count($fileObj). Array of file

Comment: do you mean count($fileObj) return the number of files you have uploaded?

would you please add a dump (var_dump or print_r, or kint, or dpm, what you are feel free with) of the `$fileObj` to question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$fileObj = $form_state->getValue('upload_doc');
if (count($fileObj) >= 4) {
  $form_state->setErrorByName('upload_doc', $this->t("<em>Only 3 images are allowed per run</em>."));}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an [opened issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3031989) to get this feature out of the box.

In the meanwhile, you can implement "element_validate" in your form:

```
$form['file_managed'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => $this->t('Files'),
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#cardinality' => 3,
  '#element_validate' => [
    'your_module_max_files_validation',
  ],
];
```

Then in your_module.module:

```
/**
 * Custom validation handler. Validate number of files.
 */
function your_module_max_files_validation($element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form) {
  $is_removal = strpos($form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'], 'remove_button') !== FALSE ? TRUE : FALSE;
  if (!empty($element['#cardinality']) && count($element['#files']) > $element['#cardinality'] && !$is_removal) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName($element['#name'], t('Only max @limit files allowed.', [
      '@limit' => $element['#cardinality'],
    ]));
  }
}
```